# Is a webcam-based program in python possible for my project?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, circuit

I'm going to do a project on wheatstone bridge. So the idea is to replace a bulb instead of the voltmeter. Bulb will change in brightness according to the fluctuation of R4(resistor).

However I'm looking for programming of a analyzer to analyse this change of the bulb and use it as a input for my program. I want to do this with python. I know they have libraries for it like pygame, opencv, numpy, PIL etc.

Ultimately I want to calculate RGB values in each pixel and continuous update on them so that values get changed with the bulb.

I have never programmed these kind of things with webcams before. 
1).  Do you think it is possible?
2).  give me anything you come up with in this regard if you were to do this.

thank you.

Comment: Interesting (and quite probably, great fun), but wouldn't you agree that this approach has a pretty pronounced [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) ring to it?

Comment: @fvu is it?. well this was kind of a idea popped out of my head recently. I don't really see anything wrong with it. I mean other than go for aurdino or something I don't know how to take signals into my pc. I can't afford expensive things in my situation.

Comment: That's why I said interesting and fun, but my gut feeling is that it will be extremely complicated to get a reasonable and repeatable precision. An Arduino could spit out the analog value it reads to your pc via its serial interface, at least there you have 10 bits of resolution and reasonable stability. Another inexpensive solution could be [this little gizmo](http://www.raspberryworx.com.au/shop/8-channel-usb-gpio-module-with-analog-inputs/)

Comment: What is the status on this question? Have you already found a solution? If not, could you describe your development environment (e.g. Windows/Linux/Mac, Python 2.X/3.X)